# Using easy-fit in an angularjs application without requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, babeljs

I m trying to use a js library easy-fit (https://github.com/pierremtb/easy-fit) in an angularjs application (https://github.com/khertan/forrunners).

Easy-fit use gulp, babel. And i would like to transpil and compile to a unique javascript file.

How can i use gulp-babel to transpile without require call ?

Thank you,

Comment: Hmm, easy-fit is npm module. Probably you need to use browserify? http://browserify.org/

Comment: I don't see RequireJS used anywhere in easy-fit. In case it need be said: RequireJS is a specific loader for AMD modules. Not all uses of the function `require` are uses of RequireJS. If I did miss its use please edit your question to present your evidence that RequireJS *is* used there.

Comment: Oups ... thank you. Indeed it use require and not requirejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading documentation

There is no requirejs dependancy at all.

But as there is some require() call in the lib which is a node method, browserify the lib is required...

How i ve made and used the lib

```
$ browserify easy-fit.js --standalone easy-fit > easy-fit.bundle.js
```

Include it in your index.html :

```
<script src="lib/easy-fit.bundle.js"></script>
```

And now call it in your javascript :

```
var EasyFit = window.easyFit.default;
```